# API Gateway Authorizer Accepts ID_token But Not Access_Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am using API Gateway and an Authorizer to control access to a folder in an S3 bucket. The Authorizer is configured to use a Cognito User Pool. This user pool has the OAuth Scopes `phone` and `email` associated with it and also a custom scope which I intend to grant read access to the S3 bucket.

I am finding however that the Authorizer will only accept the ID token to grant access and returns unauthorized if I pass the access token. According to the [Amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) it should be possible to use an access token.

I have followed the direction given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html) when requesting an access token so for example I set up the `auth` variable like so:

```
var authData = {
        ClientId : '<removed>', 
        AppWebDomain : '<removed',
        TokenScopesArray : ['openid','email', 'domain.com/content/content.read'], 
        RedirectUriSignIn : '<removed>',
        RedirectUriSignOut : '<removed'
    }
```

I had assumed that an access token would be all that I required and that was its purpose but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Is the problem occurring when making a request to the API gateway? If so, how are you passing the token in the request?

Comment: In the `Authorization` header. It works when the ID token is passed in but not the access token.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use API Gateway with an access token you have to jump through a few extra hoops.

For full details take a look at "[Integrate an API with a User Pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html)", especially the section on configuring a COGNITO_USER_POOLS authorizer **on methods**.

Specifically, from the Method Request's Settings > Authorization:

> - Choose the pencil icon next to OAuth Scopes.
> - Type one or more full names of a scope that has been configured when the Amazon Cognito user pool was created. For example, following the
>     example given in Create an Amazon Cognito User Pool, one of the scopes
>     is com.hamuta.movies/drama.view. Use a single space to separate
>     multiple scopes.
> - To save the setting, choose the check mark icon.

Comment: This feels like a face-palm moment. Although I had read the _beginning_ of that page you linked I did not read the _whole_ of it. I'll try that and see if that (most likely) fixes my issue.

Comment: I have no end of time and sympathy for anyone attempting to make sense of Cognito documentation. AWS does not make it easy.

Comment: Embarrassingly obvious really now .. there is a box for OAuth scopes right under the Authorization selection... but thanks. The AWS docs have all the information but I sometimes think the presentation could be better.

Answer (score 0):

To make access_token work with GW API:

Cognito user pool OAuth 2.0 Setting are as follows

[image]

Use the following settings in Gateway API method execution

[image]